# Matlab - How to mask a 3-D image using a binary image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I have an image with red, green, blue channel and a binary version of the image.

What I want to do is concatenate those 2 images so that the binary image works as the mask for the normal image.

I want to select only the pixels from the color image which are 1 in binary.

I know that this should work with `cat`, or even with `repmat`, but since I'm pretty new to Matlab I can't figure out how to do this, even after reading the docs of the functions.

Comment: How is that supposed to work with `cat` or `repmat`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a 3-D image `I` and a binary mask `M`, you can mask the irrelevant bits to zero either by multiplying the image by the mask:

```
I = bsxfun(@times, I, M);
```

or by logical indexing:

```
I(~mask(:, :, ones(1, size(I, 3)))) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understood your problem, but here goes one suggestion:

Suppose `rgbIm` is your *RGB image*, and `bwIm` is your *binary image*;

You may try to "expand" your binary image to "*3D*" (so that its dimensions are consistent with the original RGB image) with the following line of code:

```
bwImAux = bwIm(:,:,[1 1 1]);
```

And then perform a simple **multiplication** to "eliminate" all the pixels that **are not ones** in the binary image:

```
rgbImNew = rgbIm.*bwImAux;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the binary image as a logical index in the 3dim image. To zero all pixels in `image` that are zero in the binary `mask`, you can use the following code for each dimension: `image(~mask)=0;`