# Creating intensity band across image border using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have this image (8 bit, pseudo-colored, gray-scale):
[image: original image]

And I want to create an intensity band of a specific measure around it's border.

I tried erosion and other mathematical operations, including filtering to achieve the desired band but the actual image intensity changes as soon as I use erosion to cut part of the border.

My code so far looks like:

```
clear all
clc
x=imread('8-BIT COPY OF EGFP001.tif');
imshow(x);
y = imerode(x,strel('disk',2));
y1=imerode(y,strel('disk',7));
z=y-y1;
figure
z(z<30)=0
imshow(z)
```

The main problem I am encountering using this is that it somewhat changes the intensity of the original images as follows:

[image: actual result]

So my question is, how do I create such a band across image border without changing any other attribute of the original image?

Comment: This is the main image I am working on.
http://i.imgur.com/xbSqscC.png

This is kind of how I would like the band be-
http://i.imgur.com/bNPSCvo.png

Comment: I've added those 2 images to your question. Could you also upload what you actually get with this code, even if it's not what you want to get?

Comment: Thanks for adding them. The aftermath I got after applying the code is this- 
 (http://i.imgur.com/ZM9u02d.jpg), actually this is something closer to what I desire but my code changes the intensity of the original image which I want intact. So i was wondering if there are other ways to do this...

Comment: I'm confused on how you went from the first image to the second image.  How come the colour distribution has changed?  Can you provide some insight on how that colour should change?  Judging from the context of your code, you seem to want to introduce that black filled contour within the interior of the main object while leaving the rest untouched.  Can you please clarify or elaborate a bit on this step?

Comment: I hope I've added your images in the right order, because I'm also not quite sure if I understand the question... Otherwise please edit the question. Do you think this is a question of displaying the image or of the actual transform? Do you know the intensitiy of the region you would want to highlight?

Comment: The 2nd image was creating confusion so I deleted it. Basically the 1st image is a pseudo colored gray-scale image where I want to create a band across it's border like the last image while keeping the intensity intact. But the problem rises while using my code, the intensity of the main image changes while creating the band. Now I am looking to create the band without changing any other factors. 
I hope the question is clear now.

Comment: @ShafiulMunir - So would you like to create a band of constant intensity that surrounds the border of the main object?

Comment: If the width of the band in the final image is what you want, you can threshold that image to get a binary mask, then apply that mask to the original. That should give you a border with the same intensity as the original image.

Comment: @rayryeng, yes, a band, but not of constant intensity, the intensity remains the same as the original image, I want to extract a certain portion of main image (a band across the border just like the 2nd image). In the main image the outside borderline stays intact along with all properties, middle part vanishes.

Comment: Then do what beaker says.  That is your answer.

Comment: @beaker, can you elaborate on how would I be able to do what you suggested, it would be very helpful if you could share a code. And initially I don't have the final image, I have to create something like that from the original, I only have the original.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have access to Matlab on my laptop, but working from your image `z` above, `mask=im2bw(z,threshold(z));` Then use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633917/matlab-how-to-mask-a-3-d-image-using-a-binary-image) post to apply the mask to your original image. The bad new is that it appears that the eroded band is narrower than the object in the original image, so it's not exactly what you want. Perhaps @rayryeng has some ideas on creating a better mask.

Comment: Thanks for providing valuable assistance, I hope to solve the problem with the insights I achieved here.

Comment: @ShafiulMunir - I've written an answer that essentially mimics beaker's procedure to you with some slight modifications on my end.  Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, I am participating here just from yesterday and didn't know the procedures very well, but I have found how to accept an answer now and your answer is very helpful to my studies. I will be posting if further queries comes up. Thanks again.

Comment: @ShafiulMunir - No problem at all.  Keep the questions coming, and I'm glad to have helped!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going with what beaker was talking about and what you would like done, I would personally convert your image into binary where `false` represents the background and `true` represents the foreground.  When you're done, you then erode this image using a good structuring element that preserves the roundness of the contours of your objects (`disk` in your example).

The output of this would be the interior of the large object that is in the image.  What you can do is use this mask and **set these locations in the image to black** so that you can preserve the outer band.  As such, try doing something like this:

```
%// Read in image (directly from StackOverflow) and pseudo-colour the image
[im,map] = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxFwB.png');
out = ind2rgb(im, map);

%// Threshold the grayscale version
im_b = im > 10;

%// Create structuring element that removes border
se = strel('disk',7);

%// Erode thresholded image to get final mask
erode_b = imerode(im_b, se);

%// Duplicate mask in 3D
mask_3D = cat(3, erode_b, erode_b, erode_b);

%// Find indices that are true and black out result
final = out;
final(mask_3D) = 0;

figure;
imshow(final);
```

Let's go through the code slowly.  The first two lines take your PNG image, which contains a grayscale image and a colour map and we read both of these into MATLAB.  Next, we use [`ind2rgb`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2rgb.html) to convert the image into its pseudo-coloured version.  Once we do this, we use the grayscale image and threshold the image so that we capture all of the object pixels.  I threshold the image with a value of 10 to escape some quantization noise that is seen in the image.  This binary image is what we will operate on to determine those pixels we want to set to 0 to get the outer border.

Next, we declare a structuring element that is a disk of a radius of 7, then erode the mask.  Once I'm done, I duplicate this mask in 3D so that it has the same number of channels as the pseudo-coloured image, then use the locations of the mask to set the values that are internal to the object to 0.  The result would be the original image, but having the outer contours of all of the objects remain.

The result I get is:

[image]