# How to use a label matrix to isolate a part of the image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, blob

I am working with RGB images that have one object each set against a background of a contrasting color. By filtering out noise and converting the image to a binary image I am able to obtain an image that only contains the object in white set against a black background with no holes or stray white pixels. I am able to use the BWlabel command to obtain a label matrix for the object. Would it be possible to use the label matrix to isolate the object in the original RGB image? If so, how should I go about doing this and generating a new image with only the object?

Comment: post the code you already have and an example image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633917/matlab-how-to-mask-a-3-d-image-using-a-binary-image

Comment: First create your mask by isolating out the object you want by doing `mask = I == n;` where `n` is the ID of the object you want to isolate using `bwlabel`.  After, use the post in the duplicate link.